# 'docker-compose' is not a docker-machine command error using docker-compose with docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm just starting with Docker and I'm using docker-machine on VirtualBox as I'm on an older Mac. `docker-machine` commands work fine and I'm now trying to use docker-compose to run a multi container app. I remember reading in the manuals the sentence "`docker-machine` can now run `docker-compose` commands with or without the `-`" but I can't find it anymore so I'm stuck on how to use docker-compose.. Can you point me in the right direction to use compose with docker machine. As always thank you very much for the help.
Cheers

Comment: Are you thinking of [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/)?  If you've done the `eval $(docker-machine env)` step to set the relevant Docker environment variables you shouldn't need to do anything special to use Compose.

Comment: @David Maze Hi, indeed I did eval $(docker-machine env) but then docker compose command `docker-compose up` doesn't get accepted and I get the `command not found: docker-compose` error. What else could I check after starting the machine?

Comment: You may need to separately install Compose on your host (or use a very new Docker that has it built into the core `docker` command).  It's not directly related to Machine at all.

Comment: Indeed. I Installed with brew..as I installed Docker and I guess that Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5 doesn't have it. Thanks

Comment: So I guess I'm getting a bit confused here.. Docker install does come with docker-machine as I'm using it to create virtual machine which creates and runs single containers from a `Dockerfile` in the root of my app. If Instead I need to create a multi service app (EG. Node.js app + mongoDb) I need to use docker-compose ( separate install or new docker install ) which reads from a docker-compose.yaml file and build the container for the app from the Dockerfile + the container for the mongdDb and connects the internally.

Comment: Now If I'm correct so far my confusion is: Do I need to start the default machine  `docker-machine start default` and connect my shell `eval $(docker-machine env)` if I will use docker-compose or there is no need to start the machine and just connect my shell `eval $(docker-machine env) `?

Comment: @David Maze Ok..I think I got it now after running `docker-compose up`... docker-machine creates a virtual machine ( docketing virtual host ? ) in which containers are run.. then `Docker` builds (`build` command) images from a `Dockerfile` (eg Node.js app) and runs( `run` command) the container created from that image.  `Docker-compose` builds multiple containers (internally connected) one from the same `Dockerfile` (I see it builds an image and tags it as the project name) and the rest from docker images and runs it. So indeed I have to start the default machine to use Docker-compose